# Ionic LocalStorage - Data doesnt persists

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have been trying to use local storage on ionic but my data gets lost after refreshing or after closing and re opening app. I have this module

```
angular.module('ionic.utils', [])

.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    set: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = value;
    },
    get: function(key) {
      return $window.localStorage[key];
    },
    setObject: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function(key) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    }
  }

}]);
```

and I am using the set and get method to store and extract a variable (integer),  but when I close the app or refresh the page, the data doesn't get saved and I get back just an undefined value.

```
 $scope.currentLevel = $localstorage.get("level");

  if ($scope.currentLevel = "Undefined"){
     $scope.currentLevel = 1;
  }
```

always returns 1 instead of previously setted number higher than 1

Comment: `if ($scope.currentLevel = "Undefined"){` you probably want to use the equality operator, `==`, not the assignment operator, `=`.

Comment: Wow, to believe it was the most basic thing. Thank man!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have made a **typo**. It should be comparison operator `==` and not assignment `=`.
Look at [Deep C Secrets -- Million dollar bug](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298).